# How to merge an arbitrary amount of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given any amount of dictionaries, how would one go about merging them all together, such that the merged dictionary contains all the dictionaries' elements as well as summing similar key values.

eg.

```
d1 = {a: 2, b: 3, c: 1}
d2 = {a: 3, b: 2, c: 3}
d3 = {b: 8, d: 2}
```

our merged dictionary would look like such:

```
{a: 5, b: 13, c: 4, d: 2}
```

Can this be done via kwargs? I am aware that one can do:

```
{**d1, **d2, **d3}
```

But can this be done for n-defined dictionaries?

Comment: Even if kwargs could be applied to an unlimited number of dictionaries, I don't think it would be a good idea to use it here, since it doesn't add up keys, it discards them. Your `{**d1, **d2, **d3}` expression evaluates to `{'a': 3, 'b': 8, 'c': 3, 'd': 2}`, not `{a: 5, b: 13, c: 4, d: 2}`.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem to line up with the input you posted. Shouldn't it be `{a: 5, b: 13, c: 4, d: 2}`?

Comment: Yes, thank you - I've updated it accordingly

Answer (score 2):

you can use a Counter

from collections import Counter

```
d1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}
d2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d3 = {'b': 8, 'd': 2}

list_of_dicts = [d1, d2, d3]

cnt = Counter()

for d in list_of_dicts:
    cnt.update(d)

print(cnt)
```

---

```
Counter({'b': 13, 'a': 5, 'c': 4, 'd': 2})
```

Comment: How does this fare against a `defaultdictionary(int)`? From what I can tell, order doesn't matter when using a Counter, whereas order is maintained via a defaultdict

Comment: @OrangeReceptacle - `Counter` and `defaultdict` are both subclasses of `dict` so I would expect ordering behavior to be the same (but note that order in this case is dependent on which version of Python you are using as well as the insertion order that results from the loop or other approach you use to create the `Counter` or `defaultdict`).

Comment: dictionaries are not sensitive to order themselves so I would neither expect defaufltdict nor counter to be

Comment: @Raphael - actually that depends on Python version, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: @benvc this is interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment regarding [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), here is an approach along those lines. That said, I prefer the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) approach in the answer from [@Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10766766/raphael).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def mergesum(*dicts):
    merged = defaultdict(int) 
    for k, v in (item for d in dicts for item in d.items()):
        merged[k] += v

    return merged


d1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}
d2 = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d3 = {'b': 8, 'd': 2}

result = mergesum(d1, d2, d3)
print(result)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 5, 'b': 13, 'c': 4, 'd': 2})
```